# UICollectionView resize self-sizing cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionView, which has self-sizing cell implemented by `estimatedSize` and `preferredLayoutAttributeFitting`. This collection view has many different cells, and each type of cell is used once. Everything worked fine, until I had to be able to dynamically resize these self-sizing cells. When a cell that has a horizontal scrollview(and some of them do) is scrolled to a page with longer or shorter content, I need to resize the cell to accommodate this change. I have updated the constraints of the subviews of the cell, and it worked, but I could not get the collection view to re-layout the cells. If I call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`, or `collectionView.reloadData()`, or both, all the cells disappear or appear at a wrong position, overlapping each other or going out of bounds. However, the contentSize(the scrollable size) of the collectionView is still correct.

Any ideas?

Note: I have these cells cached to variables so that I don't initiate a new instance upon reload. The phenomenon still appears even when I disable caching.

Comment: You don’t have to cache cells into variables you could use deque cell. If you use auto layout, set constraints to the content view on the cell and set the item size to automatic dimension in the flow layout and set the estimated item size then it should work. Auto layout determine the size of the item automatically

Comment: Will flow layout update the constraint for me if there are any changes?

Comment: Nope, flow layout arranges the cells in the form of a grid. As part of it you get to build auto resizing cells. It is up to you to build the constraints for the collection view and the constraints for the cell. Please read the documentation

Comment: My question is, how to let flow layout re-layout the cell when I change the constraint? invalidateLayout() doesn't work

Comment: In my humble view the cell should be light and should resize based on the content without having to change constraints. I wouldn’t recommend to have a scroll view within a cell. Use a UIPageViewController or an alternate approach. Draw a block diagram what you want to achieve.